# Hide the quick launch on a specific page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am new here, to StackExchange & SharePoint 2013

I've been pulling my hair out over the past few days getting my head around some (what i believe to be) relatively simple features.

I'm developing a mobile phone request/management system where by users fill in a request form for a new mobile phone and upon clicking save they're redirected to a thank you page. I've managed to sort out the redirecting using a ?SOURCE= direct to a page I've created through sharepoint designer 2013. I would rather not have the users able to access any of the options on the quick launch so in my mind id like to be able to hide or delete the quick launch on the left hand side but not anywhere else through the site.

Is there a simple solution to this? I'm not completely stupid on this but i am relatively new to sharepoint 365

I have a number of other questions but ill keep those separate!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please apply this css on your page.

```
<style>

#sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }

</style>
```

**EDIT:**

As you need to hide Quick launch only on one page, please add this css to only that page(If you are using SharePoint Designer). Just edit your page in SharePoint Designer.

However, if you don't want to edit the page in Designer and want a OOB solution,i would suggest you to add a Content Editor WebPart to the page OOB and then copy paste the css written above. 
That would Help.

Please let me know if you need further explanation.

[Help Link](http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/blog/2013/07/25/easily-hide-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Comment: Please improve your answer. Adding a code snippet doesn't help someone who is new to SharePoint.

Comment: @StefanBauer Sure :). I am adding more details. Please feel free to improve my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Please merge and apply this css on your page. to hide quicklunch (and if ribbon)

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">

    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = &quot;WSSEndUser&quot;;

    </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>

    <SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
   #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .s4-ca {margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    .ms-core-navigation { display: none; }
    #contentBox { margin-left: 0; }
    </SharePoint:StyleBlock>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

    <SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">    #s4-ribbonrow, .ms-cui-topBar2, .s4-notdlg, .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, .s4-notdlg noindex, #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, #s4-titlerow, #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, #s4-leftpanel-content {display:none !important;}
    .s4-ca {margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important;}
    .ms-core-navigation { display: none; }
    #contentBox { margin-left: 0; }
    </SharePoint:StyleBlock>

</asp:Content>
```